# Where and how to define variables for URLs etc

Tags: variables, constants

I have one online version of a site, and one developer version which I am working and making changes on.

If I have a form with a url which the user will be redirected to:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="cancelurl" value="https://mytemporarysite.com/cancel/">
```

So when updating the live site, I have to change the url to the one that's valid for the live version.

So it would be more preferrable to use a variable or constant which is defined somewhere.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cancelurl" value="<?php $cancelurl ?>">
```

Then I can transfer the code without having to change the urls.

So my question is where and how do I define such variables or constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just use [`site_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) + the path - so for instance:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cancelurl" value="<?php echo site_url('/cancel/'); ?>">
```

Comment: Okay, that should work! Beause i's the same folder structure. And the page is directly in the main folder. Why didn't I think of that? If the page would have been in a different folder on each site, I would have needed some other solution, but this will solve the problem I think.

Comment: Yeah, it's amazing how many variables/constants WordPress supplies. I just found this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

Comment: Btw, I ended up using "home_url()" because "site_url()" added "/wp" to the domain name.